# Unexpected results when joining two subqueries with SQLAlchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a large SQL table as follows,

```
Id       Firstname       Lastname        tran_id      insert_datetime
==============================================================
1           Tom              Smith             0         2020-08-07 15:37:32
2           Tom              Smith             0         2020-08-06 06:33:44
3           Tom              Smith             1         2020-08-07 12:43:53
4           Foo               Bar              7         2020-08-24 23:43:21
5           Foo               Bar              0         2020-08-25 14:23:24
....
```

and I'm trying to group it by (`firstname`, `lastname`, `date`) and obtain the number of transactions except those with `tran_id = 0` as follows:

```
Firstname       Lastname        date          num_tran
==============================================================
Tom              Smith         2020-08-25         0         
Tom              Smith         2020-08-26         2         
Foo               Bar          2020-08-25         1        
Foo               Bar          2020-08-26         0        
....
```

I was able to achieve this in MySQL by doing the following:

```
SELECT a.firstname, a.lastname, a.date,
CASE
    WHEN b.num_tran IS NOT NULL THEN b.num_tran
    ELSE 0
END AS num_tran
FROM 
(SELECT firstname, lastname, DATE(insert_datetime) AS date
FROM table
WHERE a.insert_datetime >= '2020-08-25' AND a.insert_datetime <= ' 2020-08-27'
GROUP BY firstname, lastname, date
) a
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT firstname, lastname, DATE(insert_datetime) AS date, COUNT(Id) AS num_tran
FROM table
WHERE tran_id != 0 AND a.insert_datetime >= '2020-08-25' AND a.insert_datetime <= ' 2020-08-27'
GROUP BY firstname, lastname, date
) b
ON a.firstname = b.firstname, a.lastname = b.lastname, a.date = b.date
```

I tried to transform this to SQLAlchemy as shown below:

```
from sqlalchemy import func, case, cast, Date
from sqlalchemy.sql import label

# First full table subquery
full_table = (
    request.dbsession.query(
        table.firstname,
        table.lastname,
        label('date', cast(table.insert_datetime, Date))
    )
    .filter(
        table.insert_datetime >= '2020-08-25',
        table_insert_datetime <= '2020-08-27')
    .group_by(
        table.firstname,
        table.lastname,
        cast(table.insert_datetime, Date))
    .subquery()
)

# Second subquery
num_transactions = (
    request.dbsession.query(
        table.firstname,
        table.lastname,
        label('date', cast(table.insert_datetime, Date)
        label('num_tran', func.count(table.id))
    )
    .filter(
        table.tran_id != 0,
        table.insert_datetime >= '2020-08-25',
        table.insert_datetime <= '2020-08-27')
    .group_by(
        table.firstname,
        table.lastname,
        cast(table.insert_datetime, Date))
    .subquery()
)

# Left outer join to get final table
result_table = (
    request.dbsession.query(
        full_table.c.firstname,
        full_table.c.lastname,
        full_table.c.date,
        case(
            [(num_transactions.c.num_tran == None, 0)],
            else_=num_transaction.c.num_tran)
        .label('num_tran'))
    .join(num_transactions,
          (full_table.c.firstname == num_transaction.c.firstname) &
          (full_table.c.lastname == num_transaction.c.lastname) &
          (full_table.c.date == num_transaction.c.date), 
          isouter=True)
)
```

However, I get tens of thousands of results and it obviously does not match the results of the query in MySQL. Is there somewhere I'm going wrong in how I'm writing the query using SQLAlchemy?

Comment: In `table_insert_datetime <= '2020-08-27'` it looks like you are comparing against a value, not the `table.insert_datetime`. Is that a typo in the question itself, or also in your actual code? All in all `print(str(result_table))` is a good first step in debugging queries.

Comment: Regarding the query, if you want to skip 0 while counting, you could employ the fact that `COUNT` does not count NULL: `SELECT firstname, lastname, DATE(insert_datetime) AS date, COUNT(NULLIF(tran_id, 0)) AS num_tran WHERE insert_datetime BETWEEN '2020-08-25' AND '2020-08-27' GROUP BY firstname, lastname, date`